# Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine cannot find trainer module for local execution

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I try to get my feet wet with Google Cloud [Machine Learning (ML) Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine) by attempting to run a local trainer. I have followed Google's setup instructions and issued this command:

```
gcloud ml-engine local train \
  --module-name trainer \
  --package-path $(pwd) \
  --job-dir $JOB_DIR
```

My trainer exists in a file `$(pwd)/trainer.py`, yet I receive this error message:

```
~/cmle-quickstart/bin/python: No module named trainer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code must be in a valid [Python package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), which will require you to have an `__init__.py`, which can be blank.

First, create the `__init__.py`. From the same directory as above run:

```
touch __init__.py
```

To run local training, you'll need to refer to module by its fully qualified name, which now includes the parent directory of the module. So if your directory structure looks like this:

```
- my_model
  - __init__.py
  - trainer.py
```

Then the package name is `my_model` and the module name is, of course, `trainer`. So to run training, you would use the following commands:

```
gcloud ml-engine local train \
  --module-name my_model.trainer \
  --package-path $(pwd) \
  --job-dir $JOB_DIR
```

Here, you're telling `gcloud`: I have a valid Python package at `$(pwd)`. The fully-qualified module name within that package that I want you run is `my_model.trainer`

Note that this is equivalent to the following command:

```
(cd $PACKAGE_PATH/.. && python -m my_model.trainer)
```

Where `PACKAGE_PATH` points to the `my_model` directory.

See also the documentation on [recommended project structure](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/packaging-trainer#recommended_project_structure).